# how to list last two modified in a directory and write the differences between the files to a seperate file in linux?

Tags: linux

Goal: I am trying to find the last two modified log files in a directory and would like to compare between them and write the difference to a file. Also,in the diff file I don't want to see any common lines between them.

Comment: What technique/tool/language do you want to use? A bash script? A Java program?

Comment: what's the naming convention of those log files? show the directory tree

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your directory only contains log files (Specifically, no other directories)

```
diff  $(ls -tA | head -2 | tail -1) $(ls -tA | head -1) > outfile
```

What's going on here:

`ls -tA` lists all files in the directory organized by date. You can modify this if you have a more specific type of file that you're looking for, such as all files that end in `.log` would be: `ls -tA *.log` . Note that this includes hidden files because of the `-A` flag.

`head -2 | tail -1` grabs the second line, which is the second newest file, and `head -1` grabs the first line, which is the newest file. There's probably a better way to do this step, but this does the job.

`diff` then receives two file names, with the first being the second newest file in the directory, and the second being the newest file in the directory.

`> outfile` prints the output from `diff` to a file named `outfile` so you can change the word `outfile` to whatever you want (Except to the name of one of your two log files, because it will be axed by the output).